# BasicScalaTemplate.toString being displayed

Tags: playframework

I have a base template which follows the pattern:
title, header, footer.

This is my base template ("main.scala.html"). All of the parameters are optional with the exception of `content: Html`.

```
@(title:String = "Untitled")(content: Html)(header: Html = null)(footer: Html = null)

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title>@title</title>
    </head>

    @header

    <body>
        @content
    </body>

    (C) 2013
    @footer
</html>
```

I used this base template with the following "index.scala.html" template.

```
@(email: String)

@main ("Home")
{
    Your email is @email.
}
{
    Header
}
{
        Footer
}
```

I use the index template from the index function in my controller.

```
  def index = Action {
    request => {
      logRequest(request)
      request.session.get("auth").map(
        email => {
          Ok(views.html.index(email))
        }
      ) getOrElse {
        Redirect(routes.Application.login)
      }
    }
  }
```

The problem is that when I try going to the index I get this:

> BaseScalaTemplate(play.api.templates.HtmlFormat$@a335c3b) ("Home --
>   Nomad") { Your email is test@example.com } { Header } { Footer
>   }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Perhaps the parser isn't interpreting your index.scala.html the way you expect. Try

```
@(email: String)

@main ("Home") {
    Your email is @email.
} {
    Header
} {
    Footer
}
```

Comment: Updated with a different suggestion -- didn't notice the missing parameter before.

Comment: @content wasn't being used, so I removed it from the question.

Comment: Except, at least as written in the question, content is not optional. You've provided no default.

Comment: facepalm! I just realized the "your email is" bit is the content argument! Sorry!

Comment: Your example should work according to this: http://www.playframework.com/documentation/2.1.1/ScalaTemplateUseCases